# How to get selected data from product detail page in wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show all selected data from simple products with custom options in wishlist (`image.phtml`). How to get selected data in wishlist?

Comment: First let me know, where you want to show the data

Comment: In Image.phtml, so that i can get the selected images with the help of selected color label

Comment: Ok, that means you need to get images of products correct ?
If i have 1 simple product and i upload 3 images and you want that 3 images ?

Comment: yes, I have done same in mini-cart & view shopping cart page but  in my wishlist page its showing the default thumbnail image.

Comment: Ok it showing default image because you select thumbnail as default.
if you want to show color wise image you need to use color swatches